# SQL cursor performance/Alternative?

Tags: sql, sql-server, cursor

I currently have two tables Table1 and Table 2 structure as below. As you can see table 1 contains multiple rows for column FK and the FK column makes the foreign key to the Table 2 ID column which has only one row per ID with the most recent value from table 1 ordered by ID column in Table 1.

```
    Table 1     
ID  FK  END_DTTM
1   1   01/01/2000
2   1   01/01/2005
3   1   01/01/2012
4   1   01/01/2100
5   2   01/01/1999
6   2   01/01/2100
7   3   01/01/2100

Table 2 
ID  END_DTTM
1   01/01/2100
2   01/01/2100
3   01/01/2100
```

The business requirement is to track every update in Table 2 so that point in time data can be retrieved. To achieve this I am using SQL 2016 and Temporal tables where every update to the Table 2 creates a version in the history table automatically.

To achieve the insert update process I am currently using cursors which is terribly slow and is processing around 71000 rows in 30 mins and the table has around 60million rows! Cursor query as follows:

```
    BEGIN
BEGIN TRY
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
Declare @ID as int;
Declare @FK as int;
Declare @END_DTTM as datetime2;



DECLARE @SelectCursor as CURSOR;

SET @SelectCursor = CURSOR LOCAL STATIC READ_ONLY FORWARD_ONLY FOR
SELECT  [ID],[FK],[END_DTTM] from TABLE1  order by FK,ID;

OPEN @SelectCursor ;
FETCH NEXT FROM @SelectCursor INTO @ID,@FK,@END_DTTM;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN


 UPDATE TABLE2
 set
 END_DTTM = @END_DTTM
 where ID = @FK

  IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
BEGIN
  INSERT Table2
  (
 ID,END_DTTM
  )
  VALUES (

  @FK,@END_DTTM

  )
  END

 FETCH NEXT FROM @SelectCursor INTO @ID,@FK,@END_DTTM;
END

CLOSE @SelectCursor;
DEALLOCATE @SelectCursor;
    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
    END TRY
 BEGIN CATCH
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;

    DECLARE @ErrorNumber INT = ERROR_NUMBER();
    DECLARE @ErrorLine INT = ERROR_LINE();
    DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000) = ERROR_MESSAGE();
    DECLARE @ErrorSeverity INT = ERROR_SEVERITY();
    DECLARE @ErrorState INT = ERROR_STATE();

    PRINT 'Actual error number: ' + CAST(@ErrorNumber AS VARCHAR(10));
    PRINT 'Actual line number: ' + CAST(@ErrorLine AS VARCHAR(10));
    PRINT 'Actual message: ' + CAST(@ErrorMessage AS VARCHAR(4000));
    PRINT 'Actual severity: ' + CAST(@ErrorSeverity AS VARCHAR(10));
    PRINT 'Actual state: ' + CAST(@ErrorState AS VARCHAR(10));
    Insert into ERROR_LOG
    (
    SOURCE_PRIMARY_KEY
    ,ERROR_CODE
    ,ERROR_COLUMN
    ,ERROR_DESCRIPTION
    )
    VALUES
    (
    null,
    @ErrorNumber,
    @ErrorState,
    @ErrorMessage,
    'Error!'
    );
    Throw;
   -- RAISERROR(@ErrorMessage, @ErrorSeverity, @ErrorState);
  END CATCH
END;
```

I tried using cte but I didn't see any performance gain with it, in fact it was tad slower than the cursors themselves.

Is there a better way to achieve the above using set based operation still process every row from table 1 and update 2 so that temporal table picks up the update and tracks the changes?

Comment: Please explain what the logic is that you are trying to do.  Don't make strangers try to figure out cursor code.

Comment: Gordon, I have already tried explaining the logic in my post. The code is to show what i am doing which can be ignored if not useful. If i am not clear please say so and i can try to rephrase it without any examples or code!

Comment: Show the desired result.

Comment: Table 2 values have the desired result i.e. the last row from the table 1 group by fk

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how you are running the update SQL, but I'll describe the process that I use to track changes in Oracle.

I setup a trigger on the table that I want to audit.  I create another table with the same columns, one set prefixed with OLD_ and the other prefixed NEW_.  In the Oracle trigger, you can reference the new row and old row.  I run an insert into the audit table with the old and new value, DML action type, and the TIMESTAMP.  Additionally, I'll add the database user and if possible the application user that requested the change.

In the current RAC cluster and in our ancient 9i AIX server, I could never notice any performance degradation.

Additionally, if the transaction is rolled back, it won't insert the audit record as the trigger is inside the transaction.

Don't let people tell you NOT to use SQL triggers.  While you don't want to do "crazy" things with triggers (like running queries or calling Web services), it is the perfect application for a trigger (I normally use them to add a last updated date to a row.  I don't trust the application layer for accurate information).

Comment: Thanks Doug, it doesnt matter but i am using MS SQL server but like i mentioned in my post i am using temporal tables to maintain table versioning and i dont want to make an exception for this by using triggers.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, is that all you want?

```
insert into table2(ID, END_DTTM)
    select fk, max(END_DTTM)
    from table1 t1
    group by fk;
```

Comment: Not really because that would just insert the most recent/fk record into table, what i want is first record to be inserted and subsequent ones to be updated so that temporal tables records change tracking. Also max may not be the solution as i have other fields in the table as well which will need to be inserted or updated.

Comment: Why couldn't you just insert the "version" into table 2 with a trigger?  Seems easier then running some update query every five minutes.